# Using result set from query in mathematical equation

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query to order the result set by a doing adding a bunch of different some ratio * weight. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the right syntax for it. stripping out all complexities the query would look something like this:

```
select *, 
(
    (select count(id)/(select something else that returns a number)* 20) 
    +
    (select count(something else)/(select another something else that returns a number) * 50)
    +
    etc.....
) as genNum from table order by genNum
```

am I approaching this wrong is there a more mysql-y way to do this?

Comment: is this all in one table ? looks pretty wired what you did there ^^

Comment: You need to make those select something statements each their own subselect query and put them in their own set of brackets. E.g. `SELECT( (50+50+50) + (50+50+50) ) as test` in MySQL returns 300, as expected. Run your queries individually to make sure they return the result you're after, then plug them into this query one by one.

Comment: There might be another way to do this, but your question doesn't give much guidance.  Either edit the question and show a more realistic query or add data and desired results (or best . . . do both).

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for some like this ? (selects all from one table)

example:

```
select 
    ((count(id)/fruit_amount)*20)
    +
    ((count(old)/fruit_amount)*40)
as
    genNum 
from 
    fruits 
group by 
    id
order by 
    genNum
```

in the fiddle you will see that `count(old)` will return 3 an `count(id)` returns 6. you could also `count(*)`, its the same result.

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cc6d/3)**